# Video sent to whatsapp not playing

Tags: android, share, whatsapp

In my app there is a feature where the user can share a video with the app of their choice. The code is fairly straightforward (where mediaPath is a variable of type String which is a path to a valid video):

```
File media = new File(mediaPath);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, getString(R.string.file_provider_authority), media);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setType("video/*");
String title = getString(R.string.share_video_title);
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(share, title);
if (share.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser);
}
```

Sharing works perfectly on gmail (for example) and *seems* to work fine on whatsapp as well. It compresses the video and uploads it. The recipient gets the video and is able to see a thumbnail and download it. However they cannot play the video.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution is here

```
public void shareVideoWhatsApp() {


        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(v);
        Intent videoshare = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        videoshare.setType("*/*");
        videoshare.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        videoshare.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        videoshare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);

        startActivity(videoshare);

    }
```

[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097288/share-video-on-whatsapp-from-my-app)

Answer (score 0):

Are you try this:

```
String path = ""; //should be local path of downloaded video

        ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
        content.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
        content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, path);

        ContentResolver resolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("video/*");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hey this is the video subject");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey this is the video text");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent,"Share Video");
```