# How to share mp3 to WhatsApp?

Tags: java, android

I want to share my mp3 file with External Storage on the WhatsApp application, but when I open my application and press the button, it throws it from the application. I have codes below. Can you tell me my error?`

```
Button paylas ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    paylas = (Button)findViewById(R.id.paylas);
    paylas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent sendIntent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "bod of sms");
            sendIntent.setType("*/*");
            sendIntent.setClassName("com.mec.enes", "com.mec.enes.MainActivity");
            final File file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"sesler");
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file1);

            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ""));

        }
    });
}

public void hariciYaz(){
    try {
        File dosyaYolu = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dosya = new File(dosyaYolu , "sesler");
        if(!dosya.exists()){
            dosya.createNewFile();
        }
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(dosya);
        BufferedWriter yazici = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        yazici.write("src\\main\\res\\raw\\helikopter.mp3");
        yazici.flush();
        yazici.close();
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}`

yazici.write("src\main\res\raw\helikopter.mp3");  is there an error in this code? Is the audio file in the raw folder saved to external storage like this?

Comment: add sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp"); to your intent. Refer to https://faq.whatsapp.com/android/im-an-android-developer-how-can-i-integrate-whatsapp-with-my-app

Comment: is there any problems my other code ?

Comment: do check out 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097288/share-video-on-whatsapp-from-my-app